# How to create commands with localized description in PocketMine plugins?

Tags: php, minecraft, pocketmine

How to create commands with translated description or usage using the PocketMine API in plugins?

In vanilla commands, strings of translation codes such as `%pocketmine.command.help.description` are passed. They are references to the lang file in the original PocketMine, and plugins cannot modify them.

When a player executes `/help`, the `HelpCommand` class concatenates the result of `Command::getDescription()` with the help client output format. Then, it is passed to `Player::sendMessage`, which passes the string to `BaseLang::translateString` and then `BaseLang::parseTranslation`, and then internally lookup translations at occurrences of `/%[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+/`. Throughout this process, it is not possible to add anything, unless the server `BaseLang` is replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle `DataPacketSendEvent` and modify `TextPacket`s. Make your identifier something special that you can extract from arbitrary string.

Use this event handler:

```
public function e_dps(DataPacketSendEvent $event){
    if(($pk = $event->getPacket()) instanceof TextPacket){
        $pk->message = preg_replace_callback(
            '/PluginName\-SomeRandomBytesHere\-ForSecurityGenerateThemEveryRestart\-([0-9]+)\-AnotherDelimiterHere/', function($match){
                return $this->translate($match[1], $event->getPlayer());
            }, $pk->message);
    }
}
```